# Can we see all of mathematics as an attempt to simplify computations?

Tags: computability, logic, mathematical-foundations, philosophy, hypercomputation

This is a rather strong claim, and therefore likely to be incorrect, but hear me out.

Firstly, when I talk of “computations”, I mean this in a broader sense than normally used, because **I am including “infinite computers”**, e.g. Turing machines that can perform computations not in a finite amount of steps, but infinite or even uncountable. e.g., a Turing machine that can check (using an uncountable number of computations for any subset of an uncountable $X$ whether it is open in $(X,T)$ *is allowed*.

This means my question is inherently a bit vague, because I don’t know a lot about infinite Turing machines, and I am not sure how “computational complexity” is defined for such infinite Turing machines (and not sure if it has been studied at all).

But it seems to me that if you squint your eyes, many theorems in math can be seen as performing the role of “simplifying computation”:

> **Claim**. Every mathematical definition gives a (possibly incomputable in finite time) algorithm.

**Example**. *Definition*: A function $X$ to $Y$ is continuous iff every open set in $Y$ has open preimage. *This gives an algorithm*: Check for each open set in $Y$ whether the preimage is open in $X$. (algorithm requires infinite computational time for uncountable spaces).

Many theorems can be seen as “simplifying computations”:

- Some theorems turn incomputable algorithms into computable algorithms. For example, the algorithm that checks whether a function $f$ is made up of a composition of a database of other continuous functions, is computationally simpler than the algorithm induced by the definition of continuity (though can only verify, and only for a subset of functions)
- some theorems turn incomputable algorithms into still incomputable but “less complex” algorithms.

I’m gonna make a (largely unwarranted) generalization from this:

> **Bold and weakly substantiated claim**. Every non-trivial theorem in mathematics can be seen as motivated by an attempt to reduce an algorithm (possibly requiring infinite computation) that answers questions $Q$, to a *simpler* algorithm that answers questions $Q$ or some subset thereof.

Do you think there is something to this? Are there a preexisting ideas about this?

Comment: This should probably be on [math.SE] or even [mathoverflow.SE] as you'd want to ask _mathematicians_. I'd expect the answer to be a hollering "no". Unless you generalize the notion of "computation" so much it becomes useless, there's plenty of descriptive/declarative mathematics around. Also, proofs (in non-computable domains) are not computation, and mathematics is mostly about proofs.

Comment: @Raphael, the reason I'm asking it here, is because the question is based completely on the idea of infinite computers, which is a CS topic. (Also, I'm not sure you've read what I wrote about infinite computations based on your comment).

Comment: @user56834 Actually infinite-time computation is a mathematical topic at least as much as it's a CS topic - there's a whole ton of literature under the name "generalized recursion theory" you would probably be interested in, including [infinite-time Turing machines](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808093). I do think this would be more appropriate at math.stackexchange, although I don't think it's strictly inappropriate here; it may also fit at philosophy.stackexchange.

Comment: I am gonna make a (largely unwarranted) generalization from this: **Bold and weakly substantiated claim**. Every non-trivial fact or abstraction in human knowledge can be seen as motivated by an attempt to reduce an algorithm (possible requiring infinite computation and quantum oracle) that answers questions $Q$, to a simpler algorithm that answers question $Q$ or some subset thereof. (I could claim this is my original thoughts, even though I believe it must have been folklore, regardless how much it makes sense).

Comment: Theorems cannot "turn incomputable algorithms into computable algorithms;" they may find or help formulate a (computable) algorithm for a problem, for which formerly no (computable) algorithm was known. But this knowledge has nothing to do with the computability of the problem. You would have to use the term computable in the sense of "computable according to the current state of knowledge," which is not its common usage.

Comment: @PeterLeupold you’ve misunderstood what I meant. I meant to say that a definition specifies an incomputable algorithm. I.e. that it is an algorithm that needs a infinite-time turing machine to compute. I am using computable in a more general sense than usual, namely computable by an $\aleph$-time turing machine (which may not be a turing machine in the traditional sense)

Comment: I think that my comment is absolutely independent of what model of computation you are talking about. A problem is either computable or not in the moment that the definition is clear. New theorems can only change our knowledge concerning this (non-)computability, but not the (non-)computability as such. Just like the finding of a solution to a famous problem does not change the fact that whether such a solution exists.

Comment: @PeterLeupold Let’s just leave it at this. I suggest you look up “hypercomputation”

Comment: I have quite a clear understanding of what hypercomputation means. It refers to models of computation that are more powerful than  (or uncomparable to) Turing Machines. So you are not using "computable" in a more general sense, just with reference to a different model of computation. We could also use FA-computable (instead of regular) or PDA-computable (instead of context-free) to refer to computabilities weaker than Turing-computability. My comments are true for any of these computabilities, independent of their power.

Comment: "Claim. Every mathematical definition gives a (possibly incomputable in finite time) algorithm."  This seems like a rather trivial claim unless I'm missing something.  Definitions in general have the form "A thing $X$ is defined to be $Y$ if condition $Z$."  So couldn't we always just say that determining the truth of $Z$ is an algorithm given to us by the definition?